# How is a C extension compiled with the correct native calling convention?

Tags: c, cpython, calling-convention

Suppose we're writing a CPython extension module in C.

When defining an extension, we are required to supply a `PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_<module_name>(void)`. Nowhere in this declaration is a native calling convention specified.

Whether on Linux or on Windows, how can the extension developer ensure that the `PyInit_` function is compiled using the correct calling convention, so that the interpreter calls it successfuly during runtime? Is there some magic in the Python headers that takes care of this for us? Or something else?

The same question applies to native functions contained in the extension module, and exposed to Python wrapped as function objects. How do we ensure that these are compiled in a manner compatible with the Python interpreter calling convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're literally writing `PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_<module_name>(void)`. Now `PyMODINIT_FUNC` is a macro that expands to different things that are controlled by various `#ifdef`s in `pyport.h`. In current HEAD revision in the Github revision Python 3.9 development version has these 6 defines:

```
#define PyMODINIT_FUNC Py_EXPORTED_SYMBOL PyObject*
#define PyMODINIT_FUNC PyObject*
#define PyMODINIT_FUNC extern "C" Py_EXPORTED_SYMBOL PyObject*
#define PyMODINIT_FUNC Py_EXPORTED_SYMBOL PyObject*
#define PyMODINIT_FUNC extern "C" Py_EXPORTED_SYMBOL PyObject*
#define PyMODINIT_FUNC Py_EXPORTED_SYMBOL PyObject*
```

I.e. it expands to `PyObject *` as the return type but also `extern "C"` if compiled with a C++ compiler to ensure C linkage against this symbol, *and* includes the `Py_EXPORTED_SYMBOL` on some platforms.

`Py_EXPORTED_SYMBOL` is defined in `exports.h` as one of

```
#define Py_EXPORTED_SYMBOL __declspec(dllexport)
#define Py_EXPORTED_SYMBOL __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
#define Py_EXPORTED_SYMBOL
```

None of these specify the calling convention, instead letting the function default to the cdecl convention as they should... - also do note that calling conventions are mostly a thing only in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

The default calling convention is automatically made by the compiler. `PyMODINIT_FUNC` is either `void` (in Python 2) or `PyObject *` (in Python 3), nothing more.

The Python dynamic module loader uses the default convention of the platform (not that it has any jurisdiction over that; it's to the platform).